# Word order in a Cemetery Crypt Scripture

Tags: word-usage, word-order

Which one of the following four epitaphs is the most beautiful/sentimental for a scripture on a cemetery mausoleum crypt?

I am also taking into consideration that:
Per Sempre means Forever
Sempre means Always

Thank you.

> Nei nostri cuori per sempre 
>     Per sempre nei nostri cuori
>
> Nei nostri cuori sempre 
>   Sempre nei nostri cuori

Comment: Both are correct, giving that such inscriptions do not have to follow the grammar completely (the same is true for titles). There is no verb ("essere", "tu sei" is implicit), there are no violations, the meaning is very similar - perhaps the first phrase is slightly stronger.

Comment: Also correct is _Per sempre nei nostri cuori_ (perhaps the one I personally would find more idiomatic).

Comment: _Sempre_ and _per sempre_ have different meanings. _Sempre_ = _always_, _per sempre_ = _forever_.

Comment: Would you choose *Per sempre nei nostri cuori* as the most beautiful one to put on a mausoleum crypt?

Comment: It's a very personal choice, but I would pick _Sempre nei nostri cuori_.

Comment: It's a personal choice indeed, and if this is meant for an actual tomb, I'd ask the opinion of an Italian relative or friend of the deceased. If however it is, say, for a novel, then just follow your ear: all three are correct.

Comment: Sorry, @Carole, but as it's phrased now your question is too opinion-based (everyone may have a different idea of what is beautiful) for the format of this website.

Comment: My hope is to get a majority opinion as to the most sentimental or touching of the four epitaphs provided.

Comment: @Carole, unfortunately, this site aims at giving precise, sourced answers to specific questions; it's not suited to polling opinions.

Comment: After the edit of the question, I would choose, it's my personal taste, "Per sempre nei nostri cuori" (personal taste). Then comes "Nei nostri cuori sempre", but the former gives more the impression of infinity.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  It is deeply appreciated during this time of sorrow for me.

Comment: Which of the two is correct?                     Per sempre nei nostri cuori e ricordi      
Per sempre nei nostri cuori e nei nostri ricordi